# For an orthogonal matrix $A$, Suppose $v \neq 0$, and that $Av = \lambda v$, then $A^{-1}v = \lambda^{-1} v$

Tags: linear-algebra

Whilst studying a proof about orthogonal $n \times n$ matrices with real coefficients, I come across a statement I find confusing.

It states for an orthogonal matrix $A$, Suppose $v \neq 0$, and that
$Av = \lambda v$, then $A^{-1}v = \lambda^{-1} v$. Why is this true? Seems simple enough for sure but I am unsure why you are able to replace $A$ with $A^{-1}$ and $\lambda$ with $\lambda^{-1}$ since one is a matrix and the other is a scalar?

Comment: Hint. Take the given equation $A\vec v=\lambda\vec v$ and left multiply by $\frac 1\lambda A^{-1}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@ Zachary Selk The eigenvalues of an orthogonal matrix A are real or complex conjugates in pairs and have absolute value 1. Hence, it's Determinant is 1 or -1, that is to say, A is an invertible matrix. Multiplying by $A^{-1}$ leads to $A^{-1}Av=\lambda A^{-1}v$, so $v=\lambda A^{-1}v$, and then dividing by $\lambda$ we get $$A^{-1}v=\lambda^{-1}v$$

Answer (score 1):

As per the hint. Should have figured this out but oh well:

$A^{-1} A v = A^{-1} \lambda v $ then
$v = A^{-1} \lambda v$, and then multiplying by $\lambda ^{-1}$ yields
$\lambda^{-1} v = A^{-1} v$

Comment: Good answer (upvoted) but where do you use orthogonality? (Knowing that $\lambda^{-1}$ exists). Might be good to mention.